# Adding all quantity of a specific lbc_type in cart

Tags: codeigniter, shopping-cart

i need to add all the quantity of all the product in the cart that have a lbc_type = pouch.

example:

- add to cart apple(lbc_type = pouch) user inputted quantity 2
- add to cart orange(lbc_type = box) user inputted quantity 2
- add to cart grapes(lbc_type = pouch) user inputted quantity 3

so i should get all the product in cart that have lbc_type = pouch then sum up all the quantity which based on the example the overall quantity of lbc_type = pouch is equal to 5. Because apple have quantity 2 and grapes have quantity 3

**NOTE: Each product in the product table have column name lbc_type which must contain either Pouch or Box**

MY CODES:

```
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $item)
{
        $name = $item['name']; //product name
        echo "<br>";

        $id = $item['id'];

        print_r($id); //print product_id
        echo " ";

        print_r($name); //print product name
        $data['product'] = $this->PaymentModel->getLBCType($name);
            foreach ($data['product'] as $lbctype) 
            {
                $getLBC = $lbctype->lbc_type;
                    if($getLBC == 'Pouch') //check product if lbc_type pouch
                    {

                        $qty = $item['qty']; //inputted quantity

                        echo " The Quantity of this Product is" .$qty;


                    }
            }

}
        echo "<br/>";  
        //$increment++; 
        die;
```

Comment: Products inside CI shopping cart have unique rowid, so any of them can have options. If you give options to product and add them later to shopping cart - bought products with different options figure as two different products. You can do it with options array or your own column.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 do you mean i should do $this->cart->product_option[$rowid] am i right. but in my code i've already got the product/s that specify lbc_type = pouch. the problem is getting the sum of quantity(which inputted by the user) of all products that have lbc_type = pouch.

Comment: Let me try to clear this. You go throug every item in cart, and ask database : what is this product lbc_type. If Pouch - add current item quantity to $pouch_quantity. After going through all items in shopping cart - display quantity of bought pouch/box items. Am I right?

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 ok ill explain this as short as posible. the lbc_type is column in my table in database name products. so when adding a product/s to database there is field and lbc_type is one of the field which you will indicate if that product is indicated for lbc_type pouch / box. then once the product is in the table, the user/customer can see it. then if the customer add that product/s before it proceed to cart user will indicate the quantity for that product, then system will check all of it. if there is a product/s that is specify lbc_type pouch. then all of its quantity will sum up.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 to have an idea this image is the sample of the product inside my products table. each of them have lbc_type either box or pouch http://prntscr.com/br5i08. So i want is if the customer add them to cart with a specific amount of quantity depends on what customer inputted. the system will check if there is product/s that has a lbc_type pouch in the cart. then all of its quantity will sum up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try :). First when you add item to cart, you can add any value you define. So use this possibility to store lbc_type:

```
$data = array(
        'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
        'qty'     => 1,
        'price'   => 39.95,
        'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
        'lbc_type' => 'Pouch'
);

$this->cart->insert($data);
```

Then you just simple iterate cart contents:

```
$pouch_qty = 0;
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $item)
{
    $name = $item['name']; //product name
    echo "<br>";
    $id = $item['id'];
    print_r($id); //print product_id
    echo " ";
    print_r($name); //print product name

    if ($item['lbc_type']=='Pouch') {
       $pouch_qty += $item['qty'];
    }

}
echo "<br/>";
echo " The Quantity of this Product is" .$pouch_qty;
die;
```