# Get the size of a specific size of a product in the table

Tags: codeigniter, cart

[[Adding all quantity of a specific lbc_type in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292657/adding-all-quantity-of-a-specific-lbc-type-in-cart/38295200#38295200][related) related to this topic]

I have product table. and in the table there is a column called pouch_size which has a value of 1 and 2. 1 is equivalent for small and 2 is equivalent for small.

now i just want the system to check the each pouch size of the product in the cart.

if the cart has product that have a pouch size = 1 then echo small

if the cart has product that have a size = 2 then echo large

BUT if the cart has product that have pouch size 1 and 2 then echo go to large

in my system i tried to put in the cart a products that have a different pouch size. 
then in my code. the output is just echo small and large to that specific product

```
$pouch_qty = 0;
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $item)
{
    $name = $item['name'];
    echo "<br>";
    $id = $item['id'];

    print_r($id);
    echo " "; 
    print_r($name); 
    $data['product'] = $this->PaymentModel->getLBCType($name);
        foreach ($data['product'] as $lbctype) 
        {
            $getLBC = $lbctype->lbc_type;
            $pouchsize= $lbctype->pouch_size;
            $string = strval($pouchsize);// convert int to string
            $combine = $string . $string;
            $split = str_split($string);
                if($getLBC == 'Pouch') //check if lbc_type pouch
                {
                    $pouch_qty += $item['qty'];
                        if($pouch_qty > 2)
                        {
                            echo "more than 2";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            /* PSEUDO CODE

                            -if in the cart there is only 1 product which pouchsize = 1. echo small
                            -if in the cart there is only 1 product which pouchsize = 2 echo large
                            -but if the cart has a 2 products that have different pouch size. echo small and large.

                             */
                            if($pouchsize =='1' && $pouchsize == '2')//1 small, 2 large
                            {
                                echo " small and large";

                            }
                            else if($pouchsize == '2')
                            {
                                echo " large ";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo " small ";
                            }

                        }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Again I give you a word of advice, add pouch size to your cart data. Then make some ifs.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 http://prntscr.com/brssuw i that link ive put pouch_size in the cart data. and in this http://prntscr.com/brsuhy this i put if statements already. http://prntscr.com/brsut2 and in here that's the output. the problem is if there is both small and large in the cart. the echo must be small and large. but it didnt happen. it just echo the size of the specific product. what should i do to echo it small and large? sorry for too many question im self studying CI and apply it to my system. PS. this is just the continuation of the question i ask last time about quantity.

Comment: take a look, in which loop are you? Are you in $this->cart->contents() or $data['product']?

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 im inside of both foreach coz im planning to do is once you check the all the product in the check. the next thing is check if there is lbc_type pouch and then get the qty(which you helped me before). then after that ill check what is the size of that pouch. so based on what i did is if the product/s has a lbc_type pouch then get the qty of all that product. and after that once the qty is >2 ill echo box else i will get all the size of that pouch. so if the pouch size is 1 ill echo small, if the pouch size is 2 ill echo large. so once there both 1 and 2 ill echo smal and large

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 so you could understand this is the pseudo code that ive made before. http://prntscr.com/brunpz

Comment: but you want to iterate only cart contents, not every product in db?

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 http://prntscr.com/brwl0p in this link i already erased the $data['product'] so im inside the foreach cart content. but still same output it didnt echo small and large. which is why still confused what is the wrong with my codes.

Comment: I'll be back later and try to help, take care.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 thank you so much!